# Core Animation: Setting animated property correctly

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am currently trying to build a bar graph view using Core Animation and layers.
To make it cooler I tried to let each beam pop up a bit, one after another.
For convenience I flipped the coordinate system of the view vertically.

Here's the code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
        self.values = @[@12.5f, @4.25f, @23.0f, @3.0f, @17.9f, @7.0f, @15.1f];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.beamContainer = [CALayer layer];
    CGRect frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 20, 20);
    self.beamContainer.frame = frame;
    self.beamContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.98 alpha:1].CGColor;
    float maxValue = [[self.values valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] floatValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.values.count; i++) {
        CALayer *beam = [CALayer layer];
        CGFloat beamHeight = ([self.values[i] floatValue] * frame.size.height) / maxValue;

        beam.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.6 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor;
        beam.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        beam.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width * ((float)i/(float)self.values.count), 0);
        CGRect endBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width /(float)self.values.count, beamHeight);
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width /(float)self.values.count, 5)];
        animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:endBounds];
        animation.duration = .5;
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + ((float)i * 0.1);
        [beam addAnimation:animation forKey:@"beamAnimation"];

        [self.beamContainer addSublayer:beam];
        beam.bounds = endBounds;
    }
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.beamContainer];
}
```

This works like a charm, the only problem is that if I don't write `beam.bounds = endBounds;` the beam will snap back to it's old bounds after the animation is *finished*. But when I do, It's going to use `endBounds` even before the animation has *started* and during the delay for each animation.

How can I animate the beam going from bounds A to B and sticking to B at the **end**?

Comment: Take a look at CATransaction (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), maybe it will suit your needs better. Also, see this post: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/11/prevent-caanimation-snap-back/

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
// Save the original value
CGFloat originalY = layer.position.y;

// Change the model value (this is not animated yet)
layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.position.x, 300.0);

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];

// Now specify the fromValue for the animation because
// the current model value is already the correct toValue
animation.fromValue = @(originalY);
animation.duration = 1.0;

// Use the name of the animated property as key
// to override the implicit animation
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

although it is not an exact match for the bar graph animations you are trying, you can likely get the pattern from the above example. [You can read more about it here.](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/11/prevent-caanimation-snap-back/) It helped me with a similar issue I had the other day.